# Distinct values and count in MySQL

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I have a table that contains messages that have been saved into a ORM database.I have a messages table and Users table using which I am fetching and saving values.

This is my sql query:

```
Select DISTINCT ch.user AS _id,
       con.name, 
       con.image, 
       con.color, 
       con.contact_id 
  from messages ch 
  inner join users con 
          on con.phone = ch.user 
  order by ch.timestamp ASC
```

I also have a boolean field status in the messages table. I want to get the count of all rows that have `status = false`.

Can it be integrated in my above prepared query, so that I can get all the results in a single query? Or will I need to execute another one for fetching count of rows?

Comment: MySQL or sqlite? What are you running?

Comment: Show us a couple of rows of sample output. It sounds like you want to return many rows, but you want every row to have the rowcount, which is...odd.

Comment: What kind of sense would it make to have the result above extended by another column containing the count of rows with false status with the same value for every row?

Comment: @egrunin I am sorry..i am unable to print a sample row output due my organisational policies..but the scenario is that i must get the count of message rows for every unique user whose status=false;

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub select (check [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3efa2/3)):

```
Select DISTINCT ch.user AS _id,
       con.name, 
       con.contact_id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM messages ch2 
         WHERE status = false AND ch.user = ch2.user) AS MY_COUNT
  from messages ch 
  inner join users con 
          on con.phone = ch.user 
  order by ch.timestamp ASC;
```

Or you you select from the result of the select, what might be better in terms of performance.

Comment: I am not able to get any results using this query..gives error at "("

Comment: I am posting my query as well..can you plz check where have I been wrong.

Comment: Select DISTINCT ch.user AS _id,con.name,con.image,con.color,con.contact_id ( Select count(*)  from chats ch inner join contacts con on ch.user=con.phone AND ch.status=1 AND ch.from_me=0 ) as row_count from chats ch inner join contacts con on con.phone=ch.user order by ch.timestamp ASC

Comment: Seems you are using SQLite and not MySQL? From the title I thought you are aiming for MySQL. Check this Fiddle for SQLite: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ef214/3 (works probably in Chrome only)